How to connect Props to Main Rig (parented, but still can be animated manually)
I am rigging horse for race, which has saddle which should obviously be connected to horse and follow horse movement, but still should have separate options for stirrup for jockey to move it. Saddle and horse are 1 object, only stirrup and stirrup belt is separate.
I rigged horse with autorig pro which does great job, but I don't know how to connect custom rig to it and automatically weight paint it.
Went to "Add Limb" and added Chain: Bendy Bones, but still don't know how to parent it( I'm talking about stirrup, 3D cursor is on it.

